# Command line query within Java

Tags: java, mongodb, generic-collections

I'm accessing a MongoDB and want to reuse typical command line queries also within Java.
I know it is possible to use the BasicDBObject, but I want to use command line queries like this:

```
db.MyCollection.find()
```

I tried now using the command() method of the database:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("MyDatabase");
CommandResult result= db.command("db.MyCollection.find()");
JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject(result.toString());
System.out.println(resultJson.toString(4));
```

But this returns me the following result.

```
"ok": 0,
"code": 59,
"errmsg": "no such cmd: db.MyCollection.find()",
"bad cmd": {"db.MyCollection.find()": true},
"serverUsed": "localhost:27017"
```

**How can I run a command line query within Java?**

I do not want to use the DBCollection class - because then it's not anymore possible to run queries for different collections.

```
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("MyCollection");
collection.find(); //NOT THIS
```

Comment: Why would you want to trade a perfectly save API for one vulnerable to injection attacks? Do you have a good reason for this except personal preference for syntax?

Comment: Yes, I would like to offer a small API for our non-java based software - which does not have a mongodb interface. So I need to have a class which can run different queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. With `db.command()` you are limited to [these commands](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/). Maybe you could get something like this to work (I'm having problems with getting expected results)

```
    final DBObject command = new BasicDBObject();
    command.put("eval", "function() { return db." + collectionName + ".find(); }");
    CommandResult result = db.command(command);
```

BTW, why don't you use chained calls like `db.getCollection(collectionName).find();` to avoid sticking to one collection?

Comment: Getting exception "Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on bapdocdb_pricing to execute command { eval:....  on server ...:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on bapdocdb_pricing to execute command { eval: \"...\" }", "code" : 13, "codeName" : "Unauthorized" }

Comment: @myuce Does [this](https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/555/allow-mongodb-user-execute-command-eval-mongodb-3.x#.WZLIpVUjGUk) help?

Comment: Thank you Predrag, went to use the hard way and started using aggregate function :).

Comment: @PredragMaric now eval is deprecated , any alternative way to do this

Comment: @Anshul  Don't know, sorry. Haven't been working with mongodb in a long time.

Comment: @PredragMaric no issues :)

Comment: As answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61952470/3603660 eval is removed from 4.2. There is no more way to do this using the Java Driver