# How to get the size of a single MongoDB Document in java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have searched and was not able to find a solution to this. The closest thing I found was

```
Object.bsonsize(db.test.findOne({type:"auto"}))
```

which is JavaScript not Java.

Comment: You can get the **Average Object Size** in a collection, using [db.collections.stats()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/index.html). The same command can be executed from Java code and get the average object  size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the java client, but you should be able to use it to execute your raw JavaScript. Here's a link which suggests how:

[How do I execute a MongoDB js script using the Java MongoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704284/how-do-i-execute-a-mongodb-js-script-using-the-java-mongodriver)