# call functions stored in system.js collection in mongodb from python shell

Tags: python, mongodb

Have the following function created in MongoDB server.

db.system_js.sum = "function (x, y) { return x + y; }"
This function sum is saved in current DB's system.js collection

Can execute this function in mongodb shell using
step1 : db.loadServerScripts()
step2 : sum(2,3)
output : 5.

Advice how do I call/execute the *sum function* from **python shell**?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704284/how-do-i-execute-a-mongodb-js-script-using-the-java-mongodriver).

Comment: this doesnt work. 
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: no such command: 'db.loadServerScripts()'
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: no such command: 'echoFunction(3)'

need a simple steps to execute.

Comment: Read the answers carefully. You need to use different syntax when invoking server-side JS from a driver vs the shell.

Comment: I understand, however db.eval has been removed and pymongo doesnt support it.
only the first part works well, not the second part.
More over i see your example is more on the Java code. I am looking something from python shell to execute the saved function on server.
Can you try the above code once in python and let me know pls.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot in the same way that `mongo` shell allows it.

Per [the documentation](https://github.com/mongodb/docs/commit/af1b78e23325e6d275ede6260be47be53a42511d):

> `db.loadServerScripts()` loads all scripts in the `system.js` collection for the current database into the `mongo` shell session.

Since both `mongo` shell and the server have a JS interpreter, it is possible to load scripts defined on the server (in the `system.js` collection) into the `mongo` shell.

Python interpreter interprets Python, not JS. It is not possible to load JS functions into a Python interpreter directly.

If you wish you can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136319/executing-javascript-from-python) to run JS from Python.